# File-picker not navigating into nested directories in my Charm CLI

Tags: go, command-line-interface

Im trying to create a multi-view cli which will show views conditionally. My current code actually renders the second view(file-picker) but when I press enter or right arrow it doesnt go into the child directories, instead it throws the cursor to the top ( Re-renders the file-picker I assume).
The code is taken from https://github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea/blob/master/examples/file-picker/main.go and  https://github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea/blob/master/examples/views/main.go.
Here is my full code:

```
package main
// An example demonstrating an application with multiple views.
//
// Note that this example was produced before the Bubbles progress component
// was available (github.com/charmbracelet/bubbles/progress) and thus, we're
// implementing a progress bar from scratch here.
import (
"errors"
"fmt"
"math"
"os"
"strconv"
"strings"
"time"
"github.com/charmbracelet/bubbles/filepicker"
tea "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea"
"github.com/fogleman/ease"
"github.com/lucasb-eyer/go-colorful"
"github.com/muesli/reflow/indent"
"github.com/muesli/termenv"
)
const (
progressBarWidth = 71
progressFullChar = "█"
progressEmptyChar = "░"
)
// General stuff for styling the view
var (
term = termenv.EnvColorProfile()
keyword = makeFgStyle("211")
subtle = makeFgStyle("241")
progressEmpty = subtle(progressEmptyChar)
dot = colorFg(" • ", "236")
// Gradient colors we'll use for the progress bar
ramp = makeRamp("#B14FFF", "#00FFA3", progressBarWidth)
)
func main() {
var tm tea.Model
var err error
fp := filepicker.New()
fp.AllowedTypes = []string{".mod", ".sum", ".go", ".txt", ".md"}
fp.CurrentDirectory, _ = os.UserHomeDir()
// fp.ShowHidden = true
initialModel := model{fp, "", 0, false, 10, 0, 0, false, false}
p := tea.NewProgram(&initialModel, tea.WithOutput(os.Stderr))
if tm, err = p.Run(); err != nil {
fmt.Println("could not start program:", err)
}
mm := tm.(model)
fmt.Println("\n You selected: " + initialModel.Filepicker.Styles.Selected.Render(mm.selectedFile) + "\n")
}
type (
tickMsg struct{}
frameMsg struct{}
)
func tick() tea.Cmd {
return tea.Tick(time.Second, func(time.Time) tea.Msg {
return tickMsg{}
})
}
func frame() tea.Cmd {
return tea.Tick(time.Second/60, func(time.Time) tea.Msg {
return frameMsg{}
})
}
type model struct {
Filepicker filepicker.Model
selectedFile string
Choice int
Chosen bool
Ticks int
Frames int
Progress float64
Loaded bool
Quitting bool
}
func (m model) Init() tea.Cmd {
return tea.Batch(tick(), m.Filepicker.Init())
}
// Main update function.
func (m model) Update(msg tea.Msg) (tea.Model, tea.Cmd) {
// Make sure these keys always quit
if msg, ok := msg.(tea.KeyMsg); ok {
k := msg.String()
if k == "q" || k == "esc" || k == "ctrl+c" {
m.Quitting = true
return m, tea.Quit
}
}
// var cmd tea.Cmd
m.Filepicker, _ = m.Filepicker.Update(msg)
// Did the user select a file?
// if didSelect, path := m.Filepicker.DidSelectFile(msg); didSelect {
// // Get the path of the selected file.
// m.selectedFile = path
// }
// // Did the user select a disabled file?
// // This is only necessary to display an error to the user.
// if didSelect, path := m.Filepicker.DidSelectDisabledFile(msg); didSelect {
// // Let's clear the selectedFile and display an error.
// fmt.Println(errors.New(path + " is not valid."))
// m.selectedFile = ""
// return m, tea.Batch(cmd, tick())
// }
// Hand off the message and model to the appropriate update function for the
// appropriate view based on the current state.
if !m.Chosen {
return updateChoices(msg, m)
}
// return m, tea.Batch(cmd, tick())
return updateChosen(msg, m)
}
// The main view, which just calls the appropriate sub-view
func (m model) View() string {
var s string
if m.Quitting {
return "\n See you later!\n\n"
}
if !m.Chosen {
s = choicesView(m)
} else {
s = chosenView(m)
}
return indent.String("\n"+s+"\n\n", 2)
}
// Sub-update functions
// Update loop for the first view where you're choosing a task.
func updateChoices(msg tea.Msg, m model) (tea.Model, tea.Cmd) {
switch msg := msg.(type) {
case tea.KeyMsg:
switch msg.String() {
case "j", "down":
m.Choice++
if m.Choice > 3 {
m.Choice = 3
}
case "k", "up":
m.Choice--
if m.Choice < 0 {
m.Choice = 0
}
case "enter":
m.Chosen = true
return m, frame()
}
case tickMsg:
if m.Ticks == 0 {
m.Quitting = true
return m, tea.Quit
}
m.Ticks--
return m, tick()
}
if m.selectedFile == "" {
var cmd tea.Cmd
// m.Filepicker, cmd = m.Filepicker.Update(msg)
// Did the user select a file?
if didSelect, path := m.Filepicker.DidSelectFile(msg); didSelect {
// Get the path of the selected file.
m.selectedFile = path
}
// Did the user select a disabled file?
// This is only necessary to display an error to the user.
if didSelect, path := m.Filepicker.DidSelectDisabledFile(msg); didSelect {
// Let's clear the selectedFile and display an error.
fmt.Println(errors.New(path + " is not valid."))
m.selectedFile = ""
return m, tea.Batch(cmd, tick())
}
return m, cmd
}
return m, nil
}
// Update loop for the second view after a choice has been made
func updateChosen(msg tea.Msg, m model) (tea.Model, tea.Cmd) {
switch msg.(type) {
case frameMsg:
if !m.Loaded {
m.Frames++
m.Progress = ease.OutBounce(float64(m.Frames) / float64(100))
if m.Progress >= 1 {
m.Progress = 1
m.Loaded = true
m.Ticks = 100
return m, tick()
}
return m, frame()
}
case tickMsg:
if m.Loaded {
if m.Ticks == 0 {
m.Quitting = true
return m, tea.Quit
}
m.Ticks--
return m, tick()
}
}
return m, nil
}
// Sub-views
// The first view, where you're choosing a task
func choicesView(m model) string {
c := m.Choice
tpl := "What to do today?\n\n"
tpl += "%s\n\n"
tpl += "Program quits in %s seconds\n\n"
tpl += subtle("j/k, up/down: select") + dot + subtle("enter: choose") + dot + subtle("q, esc: quit")
choices := fmt.Sprintf(
"%s\n%s",
checkbox("Choose an Aesir file", c == 0),
checkbox("Start REPL", c == 1),
)
return fmt.Sprintf(tpl, choices, colorFg(strconv.Itoa(m.Ticks), "79"))
}
// The second view, after a task has been chosen
func chosenView(m model) string {
var msg string
switch m.Choice {
case 0:
var s strings.Builder
s.WriteString("\n ")
if m.selectedFile == "" {
s.WriteString("Pick a file:")
} else {
s.WriteString("Selected file: " + m.Filepicker.Styles.Selected.Render(m.selectedFile))
}
s.WriteString("\n\n" + m.Filepicker.View() + "\n")
msg = s.String()
// msg = fmt.Sprintf("Carrot planting?\n\nCool, we'll need %s and %s...", keyword("libgarden"), keyword("vegeutils"))
case 1:
msg = fmt.Sprintf("A trip to the market?\n\nOkay, then we should install %s and %s...", keyword("marketkit"), keyword("libshopping"))
default:
msg = fmt.Sprintf("It’s always good to see friends.\n\nFetching %s and %s...", keyword("social-skills"), keyword("conversationutils"))
}
label := "Downloading..."
if m.Loaded {
label = fmt.Sprintf("Downloaded. Exiting in %s seconds...", colorFg(strconv.Itoa(m.Ticks), "79"))
}
return msg + "\n\n" + label + "\n" + progressbar(m.Progress) + "%"
}
func checkbox(label string, checked bool) string {
if checked {
return colorFg("[x] "+label, "212")
}
return fmt.Sprintf("[ ] %s", label)
}
func progressbar(percent float64) string {
w := float64(progressBarWidth)
fullSize := int(math.Round(w * percent))
var fullCells string
for i := 0; i < fullSize; i++ {
fullCells += termenv.String(progressFullChar).Foreground(term.Color(ramp[i])).String()
}
emptySize := int(w) - fullSize
emptyCells := strings.Repeat(progressEmpty, emptySize)
return fmt.Sprintf("%s%s %3.0f", fullCells, emptyCells, math.Round(percent*100))
}
// Utils
// Color a string's foreground with the given value.
func colorFg(val, color string) string {
return termenv.String(val).Foreground(term.Color(color)).String()
}
// Return a function that will colorize the foreground of a given string.
func makeFgStyle(color string) func(string) string {
return termenv.Style{}.Foreground(term.Color(color)).Styled
}
// Generate a blend of colors.
func makeRamp(colorA, colorB string, steps float64) (s []string) {
cA, _ := colorful.Hex(colorA)
cB, _ := colorful.Hex(colorB)
for i := 0.0; i < steps; i++ {
c := cA.BlendLuv(cB, i/steps)
s = append(s, colorToHex(c))
}
return
}
// Convert a colorful.Color to a hexadecimal format compatible with termenv.
func colorToHex(c colorful.Color) string {
return fmt.Sprintf("#%s%s%s", colorFloatToHex(c.R), colorFloatToHex(c.G), colorFloatToHex(c.B))
}
// Helper function for converting colors to hex. Assumes a value between 0 and
// 1.
func colorFloatToHex(f float64) (s string) {
s = strconv.FormatInt(int64(f*255), 16)
if len(s) == 1 {
s = "0" + s
}
return
}
```